# Casting pointer to ULONG_PTR to do pointer arithmetic that is compatible in 32 bit and 64 systems?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

I am writing a kernel mode driver that does some pointer arithmetic, first i get a PVOID pointer to a part of a PE module in memory, then i need to add an offset to it and compile it in a way that works for both 32 bit and 64 bit system.

Casting to INT or UINT will not work because as you all know they are still 32 bit in 64 bit systems therefore casting an address to it in a 64 bit system will cause problems.

So right now I am casting the addresses to ULONG_PTR, as seems to be suggested by Microsoft :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/rules-for-using-pointers

then do the arithmetic on it and get the new address.

Am i doing this the best way possible or is there any better option for casting it other than ULONG_PTR? because i didn't many sample code that cast addresses to ULONG_PTR.

Will i face any problem by casting an 64/32 bit PVOID address to ULONG_PTR to do arithmetic on it?

Basically i want to cast addresses to some type that is 32 bit in 32 bit system and 64 bit in 64 bit system and is unsigned, and allows me to do arithmetic on the address, and looking for the best option to cast my PVOIDs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard way would be to cast to `uintptr_t`; but if you want to be consistent with Microsoft code you'd use their nonstandard typedefs.

When it comes to doing arithmetic with an offset, the common wisdom is that a compiler can track the provenance even with an integer so if you cast a `void *` to `uintptr_t` and manipulate the resulting value so that it points to another object altogether not part of the original allocation/object and cast it back to `void *` then the behaviour will be undefined (see for example [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation)), but I am quite sure everyone does it in low-level programming anyway, and believe that Microsoft compilers wouldn't track pointer provenance that way.

Comment: The OP is navigating a PE image. The entirety of the image is mapped into memory as a whole. Does that count as a single allocation?